# CRM 2011 setting form field value but display stays blank

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Sometimes (in fact most times) when I try to set a lookup field value, the value is set and readable, but the field itself looks blank on the form.
Why might this be? All the parameters passed to `setSimpleLookupValue` look correct.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening?

This is the function which does most of the work:

```
function sgc_hr_getManager() {
  var testContactId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sgc_hr_case_initialcontact").getValue();
  if (testContactId != null) {
    // do nothing - the field already has a value
  } else {
    var employeeVal = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid").getValue();
    if( employeeVal != null && employeeVal[0] && employeeVal[0].id != null ) {
      var employeeId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("customerid").getValue()[0].id;
      employeeId = employeeId.replace('{','').replace('}','');
      SDK.REST.retrieveRecord( employeeId, 'Contact', null, null, function( employee )     {
        var managerId = employee.sgc_hr_ManagerId.Id;
        if( managerId != null ) {
          SDK.REST.retrieveRecord( managerId, 'Contact', null, null, function( manager ) {
              // the following function call correctly sets the value
              // but the control display is usually left blank
              setSimpleLookupValue( 'sgc_hr_case_initialcontact', 'Contact', manager.ContactId, manager.FullName );
          }, function(a) {
              alert('An error occured! Unable to retrieve postholder record ' + managerId );
          });
        }
      }, function(a) {
          alert('An error occured! Unable to retrieve postholder record ' + employeeId );
      })
    } else {
        alert('Cannot get employee details');
    }
  }
}
```

The setSimpleLookupValue function is the standard one as follows:

```
function setSimpleLookupValue(LookupId, Type, Id, Name) {
   var lookupReference = [];
   lookupReference[0] = {};
   lookupReference[0].id = Id;
   lookupReference[0].entityType = Type;
   lookupReference[0].name = Name;
   Xrm.Page.getAttribute(LookupId).setValue(lookupReference);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add next line before you set the value

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("sgc_hr_case_initialcontact").setSubmitMode("always");
```

Comment: Interesting - that seems to have fixed it. Any idea why?

Comment: Readonly field will not be submitted to DB for update. Because of that you need 'to tell CRM' to include this field.

Comment: Sure, but that wasn't the problem - it was being saved, just not displayed after the value was set. Oh well it works now!